# In Three.js, is it possible to replace a BufferGeometry's attribute arrays without creating a new geometry?

Tags: three.js, webgl

After a BufferGeometry has been created and rendered at least once, I need to increase the size of the geometry. Since increasing the size of the attribute arrays is not possible, can I replace the arrays with new, larger ones?

Something like

```
myGeometry.attributes.position.array = newPositionArray;
```

I've tried this, and set all the .*NeedsUpdate fields on the geometry, but I get a long string of WebGL errors. Is there something going on internally in THREE.js that would prevent me from operating this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation.

"You can emulate resizing by pre-allocating larger buffer and then keeping unneeded vertices collapsed / hidden."

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates#geometries

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can fake it (to a point).

From [the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things) (emphasis mine):

> With regards to updating BufferGeometries, the most important thing to understand is that **you cannot resize buffers** (this is very costly, basically the equivalent to creating a new geometry). **You can however update the content of buffers.** This means that if you know an attribute of your BufferGeometry will grow, ...you must pre-allocate a buffer large enough to hold any new vertices that may be created. Of course, this also means that there will be a maximum size for your BufferGeometry - there is no way to create a BufferGeometry that can efficiently be extended indefinitely.

So, by pre-allocating more than you need, and then only drawing the parts currently populated (to maintain performance), you can achieve the desired result.

Code example (from the same documentation):

```
var MAX_POINTS = 500;

// geometry
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

// attributes
var positions = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); // 3 vertices per point
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

// draw range
var drawCount = 2; // draw the first 2 points, only
geometry.setDrawRange( 0, drawCount );

// material
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 2 } );

// line
var line = new THREE.Line( geometry,  material );
scene.add( line );
```

And then to later update after adding new point information:

```
line.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, newValue );
```